# Eclipse - How to show `Run` windows again after set it `Always run in background`

Tags: eclipse, dialog, show-hide

When I hit `Run` button on Eclipse toolbar, it is minimized in background as I have checked to the box `Always run in background` of the popup dialog.

[image]

Now I want it popup back. How can I do it?

Answer (score 7):

For instant view click the 'green stack of icons' icon for feedback table 
or open:

`Window > Show View > Progress`

If you want to see it permanently then uncheck:

`Preferences > General > Always run in background`

Hope that helps.

Comment: `Preferences > General > Always run in background` is already unchecked but it is still minimized :(

Comment: @NamG.VU Have you tried restarting Eclipse after changing that preference/unchecked that box? Does the first option work - showing Progress view?

Comment: The 1st option is not what I want. I want a original popup.

Comment: I restart Eclipse already and things kept the same. I'm using Android SDK http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html